# How can I select links without id or class attributes using XPath?

Tags: html, select, xpath, find

I want to select number 4 or 5 links

i have tried using this expression:

```
//div/b[contains(text(),'Sida:')]/following-siblings::a[4]
```

but it didnt work

The code for this part of my HTML is:

```
<div><b>Sida: </b> <a>1</a> « <a>3</a> <a>4</a> <a>5</a> » <a>814</a></div>
```

Here is how its looks

[image: Link picture] https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFmug.jpg

**Sida:** 
   1 
   2 
   3 
   4 »
   814

or

**Sida:** 
   1  «
   3 
   4 
   5  »
   814

there are a long html page without any id or class name - so i need autopager in firefox to find the correct link `<a>` and automatically auto inert next page

i just need the expression to pinpoint the number 4 or 5 - but these number are changing when page number are changing

check the web page [l-like.it](http://l-like.it/?r=1)

Comment: So what's the question?  You've said what you want to accomplish, tell us what you want help with.

Comment: there are a long html page without any id or class name - so i need autopager in firefox to find the correct link <a>

Comment: and automatically auto inert next page

Comment: Very poorly formulated question!

Comment: I've changed it - hope its more understandable

Comment: @nagnus. You have a syntax error in your xpath, see my answer for a correct example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost did it yourself.

To get a node-set of two elements (which can be not what you want) you can use this:

```
//div/b[contains(text(),'Sida:')]/following-sibling::a[
                position() = 3 or position() = 4
                ]
```

**Note: Use `//` only when schema is unknown.**

To get a concatenated string value:

```
concat(
    //div/b[contains(text(),'Sida:')]/following-sibling::a[3],
    //div/b[contains(text(),'Sida:')]/following-sibling::a[4]
    )
```

Output with the input below will be `45`.

XML test sample:

```
<t>
    <div>bla-bla</div>
    <div id="test">
        <div>
            <b>Sida: </b>
            <a>1</a> «
            <a>3</a>
            <a>4</a>
            <a>5</a> »
            <a>814</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>bla-bla</div>
</t>
```

Comment: +1 Good typo catch: `following-sibling` instead of `following-siblings`

Comment: THANKS FLACK -  
Nice description -  
This expression worked perfect -  
//div/b[contains(text(),'Sida:')]/following-sibling::a[position()=4]